# python: check if a specific string is part of a filename

Tags: python, string, file, fnmatch

I have a list, where each entry consists of 5 individual random numbers:

List-output:

```
...
['00349']
['02300']
['00020']
...
```

Now I have two nested for loops. The outer loop iterates over this list. The inner loop iterates over a buch of files which are located in a separate directory. The aim is that I want to check each entry in the list if the number is contained in one of the filenames. If so, I want to copy these files into a separate target directory and break the inner loop because the item was found and continue with the next entry in the list.

Structure of a file example:

```
name_01043.json
```

I tried several things (see below) but the following version returns always false.

Here is my code so far:

```
from re import search
import fnmatch

list = []

# some code to fill the list

SOURCE_PATH = "dir/source"
TARGET_PATH = "dir/target"

for item in list:
    for fname in os.listdir(SOURCE_PATH):
        # check if fname contains item name:
        strg1 = str(fname)
        strg2 = str(item)
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(fname, strg2):
        # if fnmatch.fnmatch(fname, '*' + strg2 + '*'):
            sourcepath = os.path.join(SOURCE_PATH, fname)
            shutil.copy(sourcepath, TARGET_PATH)
            break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example where you could make good use of the glob module:

```
import glob
import os
import shutil

SOURCE_PATH = 'dir/source'
TARGET_PATH = 'dir/target'
# just use some hard-coded values for the sake of example
mylist = ['00349', '02300', '00020']

for e in mylist:
  for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(SOURCE_PATH, f'*{e}*')):
    shutil.copy(file, TARGET_PATH)
```

Comment: First of all. thanks for your help. I tried your version but unfortunately all of the files from SOURCE_PATH were copied to TARGET_PATH,  Not just the ones in the list.

Comment: Maybe all of the files match the patterns in your list. The answer provided is definitely selective. Unfortunately, without knowing your list and SOURCE_PATH contents it's impossible to explain what's happened

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(SOURCE_PATH):
    for file in files:
        if strg2 in str(file):
            # Do something
```

This for will return each path, subdirectory and file from the location. You can check file by file this way and simply check if the `str(file)` contains the string you need